# Android Layout Shape Design

Tags: android-layout, user-interface, layout, shapes

How can I create a layout similar to [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6bhh3cccy0umr3x/Sem%20t%C3%ADtulo-1.png), using shapes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are various tools available in market for good `UI` designing in android, also you can use `intelli j idea` as an `IDE` and go for its tutorials ,other links like  [appinventor](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/get-started.html) , [droidDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/) will also help you to make a good looking and impressive UI.

also if you want to create exact UI just like that you can use [frameLayout](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-frame-layouts--mobile-4877) in xml.and design it accordingly.

Comment: I work with Eclipse, I created 1LinearLayout to be the main container and 1 Linear layout for the header, the header LinearLayout I assigned a background shape with just what I wanted. Thanks for the tip, I created the layout in AppInventor and exported it to Eclipse.